# Why is there no back button in the Flutter Navigator 2.0 Example?

Tags: flutter, navigator

as I started working on a Flutter application I came across the Navigator 2.0. As the Documentation suggested, I used the code provided in the Documentation by John Ryan: https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade.

My Problem is that the example without a nested navigation has an automatically displayed back button but the [example](https://gist.github.com/johnpryan/bbca91e23bbb4d39247fa922533be7c9) with nested navigation does not. Why is that the case and is there a way to let the back button be automatically generated?

I am using the Flutter 1.25.0-8.2.pre beta channel.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not really solve this issue. As far as I can see, it has something to do with the nested Router delegates. However, I have implemented a flattened structure which uses only one router delegate and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your handler should indicate that the enclosing route should not be closed, hence returning false will resolve your issue.

changing your handler to this works:

```
    onWillPop: () async {
      navigatorKey.currentState.maybePop();
      return false;
    },
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I do not know where to put this code or which handler you mean. onWillPop seems to be a property of the WillPopScope but I do not know what I have to wrap inside the child property. Can you explain in more detail?